# Is $y' + 3xy + 2 = 0$ a linear first order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, by definition a linear first order ordinary differential equation can is: $y' + d(x) y + e(x) = 0$

Does this mean that $y' + 3xy + 2 = 0$ is not a linear first order differential equation?

Comment: why do you think, it is not??; You can add your thoughts.

Comment: is e(x) = 2 in this case ? in this case i don't see e(x) being dependent( a function ) of x, but just a constant

Comment: yes , $e(x)$ is allowed to be a constant function.

Comment: In that case, if i consider d(x) as a constant, the equation would turn in y' + h(y) + e(x) .. wheres d(x) now ? So  y´ + d(x) y + e(x) = 0 is not the ultimate model for any linear first order ordinary differential equation as you can find one in the form of -> y' + h(y) + e(x) . Am i not right ?

Comment: In this $DE$, $d(x)=3x$, but there are linear $DE$s where $d(x)$ is a constant function, e.g., $y'+3y+2=0$, here $d(x)=3$ is a constant

Comment: Hmm.So that simply means the  y´ + d(x) y + e(x) = 0  representation  becomes (specializes into ) y' + h(y) + e(x)  when d(x) is constant ?

Comment: $y'+h(y)+e(x)$ is linear first order $DE$, iff $h(y)$ is a linear function in $y$ and then $DE$ would be a special case of $y'+d(x)y+e(x)=0$

Comment: Got it, cleared my head

Comment: In that case h(y) = cosy  or h(y) = y²   would not fit into linear categorization right ?

Comment: but then if h(y) is linear, is it of the form h(y) = ay ?

Comment: in that case  y´ + d(x) y + e(x) = 0 specializas even more into y´ +  ay + e(x) = 0   right ?

Comment: and if e(x) is 0 we have a first order linear separable ordinary differential equation ... right ?

Comment: No, by linearity of $h(y)$, i meant $h(y)=a(x)y$, but you were discussing the condition $d(x)=$ contant, so yeah you are right.

Comment: yes you'll get variable separable equation if $e(x)=0$

Comment: Hmmm is it realy right to represent 15xy  as h(y) instead of h(x,y) for example ? in the case a(x) = 15x

Comment: Avatar where are you ?

Comment: Let me clear again, $y'+a(x)y+e(x)=0$ is linear first order $DE$ where $a(x), e(x)$ may be constant functions. If you write $DE$ in the form $y'+h(x,y)+e(x)=0$, then $h(x,y)$ must be of the form $a(x)y$. Previously we were discussing the case $a(x)=$ constant, so i just used the notation $h(y)$ instead of $h(x,y)$

Comment: Hm, do u now the representation of any first order ordinary differential equation ( be it linear or not ) ? Is it  y′+h(x,y)+e(x) the form of any first order ODE ( linear or not ) ?

Comment: First, order $ODE$ is written as $f(x,y,y')=0$

Comment: hmm can we derive even further representation like h(y',y,x) + g(y',y) + j(y',x) + m(y,x) + t(x) ? is really f(x,y,y′) = h(y',y,x) + g(y',y) + j(y',x) + m(y,x) + t(x)  or can f(x,y,y′) be expanded into something simpler ?

Comment: Actually first order $ODE$ is written as $y'=f(x,y)$;  $DE$ $f(x,y,y')=0$ might contain terms of the form $\sin(y')$.

Comment: but isn't sin(y') + y + x = 0 an ODE ?

Comment: yes, but not first order

Comment: What order is it then ?

Comment: some define it's order to be $+\infty$

Comment: Never heard of it, you recommend any book on differential equation  my friend Avatar ?

Comment: Boyce and DiPrima, Elementary Differential Equations, Eighth Edition , There is [this site](http://bcs.wiley.com/he-bcs/Books?action=index&itemId=047143339X&itemTypeId=BKS&bcsId=2026) also

Comment: Thanks, your inputs are appreciated

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

The equation,
$$y' + 3xy + 2 = 0$$
meets the requirements of your definition because
$$
\begin{align*}
y'&=y'\\
\color{#0a0}{d(x)}&=\color{#0a0}{3x}\\
\color{#c00}{e(x)}&=\color{#c00}2.
\end{align*}
$$
See a side by side comparison:
$$
\begin{align*}
y' + \color{#0a0}{d(x)}\;y + \color{#c00}{e(x)} &= 0\\
y' + \color{#0a0}{3x}\;y + \color{#c00}2 &= 0.
\end{align*}
$$